# How can I store the received data from nRF24l01+ module in an array (code in description)?

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, nrf24l01+, array, pointer

This is my sample RX code for 4 Tx and 1 Rx nRF24l01+ modules. I want to store all the data received from 4 pipes into an array (recArray).

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <RF24.h>

RF24 radio(7, 8);

const uint64_t pipes[4] = {0xF0F0F0F0E1LL, 0xF0F0F0F0E2LL, 0xF0F0F0F0E3LL, 0xF0F0F0F0E4LL};
char text[32] = {0}; #received data
int recArray[4]={0, 0, 0, 0}; # array to store the received bytes

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  radio.begin();
  radio.openReadingPipe(1, pipes[0]);
  radio.openReadingPipe(2, pipes[1]);
  radio.openReadingPipe(3, pipes[2]);
  radio.openReadingPipe(4, pipes[3]);
  radio.startListening();
}

void loop() {
  if (radio.available()) {
    radio.read(&text, sizeof(text));
    Serial.println(text);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to send 2 bytes to this module
the first byte is the pipe number (0xE1,0xE2,0xE3,0xE4)
and in the second byte Data

```
void loop()
{
  if (radio.available())
 {
  radio.read(&text, sizeof(text));
  for (int i=0; i < 4 ; i ++)
   {
     if( text[0] == ((unsigned char *)(&pipes[i]))[0] 
        recArray[i] = text[1];
   }
  Serial.println(text[1]);
 }
}
```